# Excel: access indirect column of defined table via cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a defined table named "January". One of its columns is called "Duration" with cell type time. Below this table I calculate the `SUM` of the column to hours which works fine:

```
=SUM(January[Duration])*24
```

Now, I have another overview table where my first column contains the months names. In the second column I want to calculate the durations again by using the content of the first column as pointer to the corresponding month table via `INDIRECT` (which works) but I am not able to access the column as above. So this does not work:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A2)[Duration])*24
```

So, how can I access the column here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INDIRECT` needs the full reference, so concatenate the column reference, as text:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A2&"[Duration]"))*24
```